# Is React native Text input have Id or something to differentiate?

Tags: react-native, expo

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={(text) => onChangeNumber2(text)}
    value={number2}
    keyboardType="numeric"
  />
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlCsy.jpg)
I am mapped this text box dynamically .. while i change the value of one textbox it changed the all textboxes

Comment: I think you're giving same value to all the TextInput , so onchange all the inputs gets updated. Can you please provide the array you're using to map?

Comment: Thanks for the response .. I did not gave any dynamic value to this textbox . initial state all are empty .. I just need to add separate values in all textbox manually thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a controlled TextInput, try instead removing the value prop or using a unique value prop for each item in the list, also as you're mapping this component don't forget to add a unique key prop.

```js
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={(text) => onChangeNumber2(text)}
    value={number2}
    keyboardType="numeric"
  />
```

You can read more about controlled inputs on the links down bellow

https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-text-input

https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Comment: Thanks mate .. Its worked , Thank you so much